# Jquery slide out menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/HfdXY/368/

That is my Jfiddle, I have a few questions.

1. Why do my buttons only slide out on the first click, then stay stationary from there on after?
2. How can I put the code in a single function instead of having two instances with the only difference being the CSS for button B is moved 40 pixels to the left.

Comment: Your jsFiddle renders strangely for me. I'm using Chrome. Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: @shatyUT wow that's way messed up in chrome it's supposed to be a slide out menu when you click A it brings up menu when you click it again it goes back to default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change the 'right' animation to 'left'. http://jsfiddle.net/73qaC/2/
   You only want to change the left pixel positions from 0 to xx and back again.
2. Updated the jFiddle above to use 1 method. This should give you an idea of how to achive this using one method.

Answer (score 0):

For your second one this is my solution

```
$("#openMenu,#openMenu2").click(function() {})
```

put like this and give the following code of your at once.and then you can seperatly create its css inside it like

```
$("#openMenu").css();
$("#openMenu2").css();
```